# Compile Error: Cannot access 'com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.OnDateSelectedListener' which is a supertype of

Tags: android

Getting a compile error

> Cannot access
> 'com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.OnDateSelectedListener'
> which is a supertype of

using,

> implementation
> "com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1"

against

> com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3

Suggestions to fix, please.

I have a bottom sheet that implements datePicker's onDateSelectedListener

```
class SampleBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener, TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener, OnDateSelectedListener {}
```

Comment: post your code pls

Comment: I have a bottom sheet that implements datePicker's onDateSelectedListener

    class SampleBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener, TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener, OnDateSelectedListener {}

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing the class that has this implementation from another module, hence the error. solved it by adding the dependency to the other module.